# How to use Global accessible object in BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, global-variables, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I want to use an object globally in Backbone Application. I was using jQuery MObile Application before.

To have a global variable, I created a file named Configuration.js which have the scripts,

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.Configuration = MyApp.Configuration || {
    OrganizationUniversalId: 'abcd-efgh-1234',
    ServiceEndpoint: 'http://myapp.net/',
    GcmSenderId : "123456789"
};
```

From other javascript files, the property can be obtained by `MyApp.Configuration.ServiceEndpoint`

This seems not to work in my Backbone application, why?

Comment: What makes you think other js files can't access global variable..?

Comment: If you want to do it, then go for it. Noone should be denied following their dreams.

Comment: But if I try to get `MyApp.Configuration.ServiceEndpoint` , its says ServiceEndpoint is undefined

Comment: Most likely the scripts are included in the wrong order then, but it's impossible to know for sure without seeing more of your code. If you can reproduce the error in jsfiddle or somewhere similar that would be good.